# matlab function "adapthisteq(image)" equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing

I am converting matlab code to c#. and I am stuck on  Adaptive Histogram Equalization(CLAHE)

```
    image2 = adapthisteq(image1);
```

is there any equivalent of this in c#, or any library I can use or any way to do this in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C code, but it's what every CLAHE algorithm is based on: [CLAHE GraphicsGems](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/clahe.c).

If you can use the OpenCV library and NVidia GPUs, you could use: [OpenCV CLAHE](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/gpuimgproc/doc/histogram.html).

Or even [OpenCV CLAHE Interface (without GPU)](http://public.cranfield.ac.uk/c5354/teaching/dip/opencv/lecture_demos/c/clahe.tgz). From [Toby Breckon](http://public.cranfield.ac.uk/c5354/).